# Microsoft.Web.Administration for IIS 8 does not display all sites

Tags: c#, iis, web, administration, iis-8

I am trying to display all sites from IIS 8 in a simple C# console application (this is just a spike, I will eventually do this in an asp.net MVC 4 application).

I copied the Microsoft.Web.Administration dll (from C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv) to \References and referenced it from there.

On my server, there are 3 sites:

- Default Web Site
- webdav
- Ardent

I am doing the following to list all the sites:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
        {
            try
            {
                if (serverManager != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(serverManager.Sites.ToString());
                    foreach (Site site in serverManager.Sites)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(site.Name);
                        Console.Read();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that, when I run this on the server, it only displays

Default Web Site

I ran

```
appcmd list site
```

and got all three.

Despite this, I would really like to use Microsoft.Web.Administration, as it seems better to do that than running command lines with appcmd from a C# application.

Please share your insight on why this might be happening.
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, but you have your console.read() in the loop so you will pause for input after the first writeline.  If you then type a key and press enter that will end your app.  as it will read the character + char(13) + char(10).  Just to be sure move it outside the loop.

Comment: @DavidMartin Wow. I feel stupid now. I had some other problems with the reference yesterday, and I solved them, but in the mean time had added that loop, and it seems I have forgot to take that read() out. This is silly, thanks for pointing it out (did not even think to check for this :( ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David pointed out in his comment, I made a silly mistake which I failed to observe. I am posting this answer in order to remove the question from the unanswered list.

The mistake was

```
Console.Read()
```

inside the foreach.